# Coremltools: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: learning_rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coremltools

I am using the following code to convert keras model to mlmodel:

```
import coremltools
import keras




output_labels = list(range(1, 43))
your_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('my_model.h5', input_names=['image'], output_names=['output'],
                                                   class_labels=output_labels, image_input_names='image')

#your_model.author = 'your name'
#your_model.short_description = 'Digit Recognition with MNIST'
#your_model.input_description['image'] = 'Takes as input an image'
#your_model.output_description['output'] = 'Prediction of Digit

your_model.save('your_model_name.mlmodel')
```

When running the code, I get the following error:

```
Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/bin/python /Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/coremlconverter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/coremlconverter.py", line 9, in <module>
    class_labels=output_labels, image_input_names='image')
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 830, in convert
    use_float_arraytype=use_float_arraytype,
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras_converter.py", line 607, in _convert_to_spec
    use_float_arraytype=use_float_arraytype,
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/keras/_keras2_converter.py", line 353, in _convert
    model = _keras.models.load_model(model, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 299, in _deserialize_model
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 768, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='optimizer')
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 147, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(config['config'])
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 154, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 460, in __init__
    super(Adam, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/TSR37/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 79, in __init__
    'passed to optimizer: ' + str(k))
TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: learning_rate

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is this, and how could I make it work?
I tried to update keras and/or tensorflow, but coremltools seems to be work only with keras 2.2.4 and tensorflow 1.15.0

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by using the same version of keras and  tensorflow in the enviroment creating the model and the environment converting the model.